# wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) when use expect method

Tags: ruby, rspec

here is my code

```
describe "my page", :type => :feature, :js => true do

  before(:each) do
    visit EnvConfig.get :app_url
  end

  it { expect(page).to match_expectation }

end
```

Trying to add gem and use it https://github.com/rprt/rspec-page-regression

Error

```
Failures:

1) my page should match expectation
  Failure/Error: it { expect(page).to match_expectation }

ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
  # ./spec/features/login_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.24 seconds (files took 0.90062 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/features/login_spec.rb:7 # my page should match expectation
```

spec_helper.rb file has next requires

```
require 'capybara' 
require 'capybara/dsl' 
require 'capybara/rspec' 
require 'rspec' 
require 'rspec/page-regression'
require 'selenium-webdriver' 
require 'site_prism' 
require 'env_config' 
require 'active_support/all'
```

and also config.javascript_driver = :selenium

Comment: Please post the full error. I expect that the error refers to the specific function that you're not giving sufficient arguments to.

Comment: Did you update your spec_helper? Are you requiring it?

Comment: I have --require spec_helper in .rspec file

Comment: @DmytroSotnikov Do you have the required stuff in the spec_helper?

Comment: Please edit the question with additional information; it's very difficult to read in comments.

Comment: @DaveNewton done

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa why I’m getting error on test execution?